# Jolla mobile ported to Nokia N9

Tags: linux, mobile

I own a Nokia N9 and would like to know if anybody has ported [Sailfish](https://sailfishos.org/) to it yet?

In case you're not familiar with Sailfish [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS) is the wiki page.

Comment: have you inquired at the [Maemo/Meego forum](http://talk.maemo.org)?

Comment: Aren't the developers testing the Sailfish OS on Nokia N9 and N950?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Sailfish OS

Comment: @Alko I don't think they would still be using it, but Jolla has used it during some demonstrations - so they were probably using it for some sort of prototyping.

Comment: @Mikel well, Sailfish OS **is** Unix (Linux based).

Comment: While an interesting question, it's barely worth an answer here: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sailfish+n9

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be solved by using an internet search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Jolla has been officially expressing [(via its twitter account) that it *wont* support a Sailfish-OS port to N9](https://twitter.com/JollaHQ/status/271569046229639169). That does not mean that it wont happen. It is simply going to be unofficial and community-driven.

Some Related discussions

- http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=90761
- http://www.jollausers.com/2012/11/unofficial-sailfish-os-support-for-nokia-n9n950/
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2087111&page=2
- http://www.allboutn9.info/2013/01/faq-about-jolla-sailfish-os.html